# Which character comes first?

Tags: string, python-3.x

So the input is `word` and I want to know if `a` or `b` comes first.

I can use `a_index = word.find('a')` and compare this to `b_index = word.find('b')` and if `a` is first, `a is first` is returned. But if `b` isn't in `word`, `.find()` will return `-1`, so simply comparing `b_index < a_index` would return `b is first`. This could be accomplished by adding more if-statements, but is there a cleaner way?

function description:
input: `word`, `[list of characters]`
output: `the character in the list that appears first in the word`

Example: `first_instance("butterfly", ['a', 'u', 'e']` returns `u`

Comment: I think Jon and me understood the question differently (first letter that's in the word -vs- letter that's first in the word). What would be your expected result for `first_instance("abcdef", ['d', 'a'])` ?

Comment: @viraptor That would be `a`. `first_instance("abcdef", ['d', 'x'])` would be `d`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function that takes `word` and a list of `chars` - convert those chars into a set for fast lookup and looping over `word` take the first letter found, eg:

```
# Chars can be any iterable whose elements are characters
def first_of(word, chars):
    # Remove duplicates and get O(1) lookup time
    lookup = set(chars)
    # Use optional default argument to next to return `None` if no matches found
    return next((ch for ch in word if ch in lookup), None)
```

Example:

```
>>> first_of('bob', 'a')
>>> first_of('bob', 'b')
'b'
>>> first_of('abob', 'ab')
'a'
>>> first_of("butterfly", ['a', 'u', 'e'])
'u'
```

This way you're only ever iterating over `word` once and short-circuit on the first letter found instead of running multiple finds, storing the results and then computing the lowest index.

Answer (score 1):

Make a list without the missing chars and then sort it by positions.

```
def first_found(word, chars):
  places = [x for x in ((word.find(c), c) for c in chars) if x[0] != -1]
  if not places:
    # no char was found
    return None
  else:
    return min(places)[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

In any case you need to check the type of the input:

```
if isinstance(your_input, str):
   a_index = your_input.find('a')
   b_index = your_input.find('b')
   # Compare the a and b indexes

elif isinstance(your_input, list):

   a_index = your_input.index('a')
   b_index = your_input.index('b') 
   # Compare the a and b indexes
else:

   # Do something else
```

**EDIT:**

```
def first_instance(word, lst):
    indexes = {}
    for c in lst:
        if c not in indexes:
            indexes[c] = word.find(c)
        else:
            pass

    return min(indexes, key=indexes.get)
```

It will return the character from list `lst` which comes first in the word.

If you need to return the index of this letter then replace the return statement with this:

```
return min_value = indexes[min(indexes, key=indexes.get)]
```

Comment: I'm not entirely familiar with the *args-syntax, so I used [list] instead; the idea is that the number of characters to compare may vary. The list will contain characters.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not the source of the downvote. I misunderstood you, but the fuction will be `def first_instance(word, list)`, not two separate functions. The list will contain the characters to check in the word (so there may be more than two characters). e.g. `first_instance("butterfly", ['a', 'u', 'e'])`

Comment: I downvoted you, because your first answer didn't match the question. And your edit has a bug which was specifically mentioned: `first_instance("abcdef", ["a", "x"])` -> `"x"` in your case.

Comment: @viraptor The assumption was made that the list will only contain letters from the word. However, I agree that was wrong assumption. Now it should be fine. I hope you will remove you downvote.